# Create specific size images based on hex value

Tags: python, image, colors

Normally I would've given this a stab already but to be honest I don't even know where to start.

I have a Dataframe with a column of Hex values, and I'd like to write a script to pick each one and create a PNG file of specific dimensions filled with that color.

```
hexValue
 2A9D8F
 9B5DE5
 EE8959
 FEE440
 5F797B
 C1D375
```

All the images I'd like to be 1080 x 1080 px. Attached is the first as an example. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```py
from PIL import Image

dummy_list = [
    "#ff00ee",
    "#ff0000",
    "#000000",
    "#00ff00"
]

for color in dummy_list:
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1080, 1080), color=color)
    img.save(f"{color}.png")
```

EDIT: Oh, and PIL is installed with:
`pip install Pillow`

Comment: This absolutely helps! Thank you very much